# noun+proper noun (omission of "the", room 16, page 19 etc)

Tags: definite-article

We know that when a noun is followed by its proper name (or a number used as a name) the article is usually omitted:

> I want to see **_doctor Johnson**
>
> **_British education expert Anthony Seldon** believes that robots will substitute teachers

> You can find utencils in **_section 5d** or you can go to **_room 204**

However, I've come across 3 interesting examples (all from the same text). The first 2 seem to follow the rule, but the 3rd one, despite having the same pattern, breaks the rule:

> When _**fast-food restaurant McDonald's**  (correct) realised that the market
> wanted healthier choices, they introduced fruit and salads
>
> in 2006, **_video games giant Nintendo** (correct) introduced **the game console
> Nintendo Wii** (why "the"??)

all 3 come from a ESL text, published on the website of British Council (https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/skills/reading/b1-reading/innovation-in-business)

All the 3 examples have the same pattern:
noun + proper name, however, in the 3rd one the article is not omitted.

When should I follow this rule and when should I not?

Comment: I've never heard the Wii called just "Wii", for what it's worth, always "the Wii".

Comment: Really? being a non-native, I always thought "Wii" was a proper name, not requiring any articles. Does "Wii" have any meaning as a noun?

Comment: No, Wii doesn't mean anything as a noun in English.  We do sometimes use articles with names in English, though - consider "the Parthenon".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with _the British education expert Anthony Seldon_ or _the fast-food restaurant MacDonalds_. The article _may_ be omitted, it doesn't have to be.

Comment: However, I can't do the same with number-names like "page 15" or "box 25" "room 12"? In this case I have to omit it, is that right?

Comment: That's right. (NB I only spotted this comment by chance because you didn't include my name!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always heard the Nintendo Wii referred to as "the Wii" in American English, at least when referring to the product in general.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried that my understanding of the rule was incorrect

Comment: But does that actually answer the question? Suppose we changed the example: "Communications giant Apple has just released the new iPhone 9." So I think there's a more general issue in play.